# Can I retrieve the Youtube Channel Details on PHP?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

For example I want to get: `https://www.youtube.com/user/<USER_ID>/about`

how to get the subscribers, page views, joindate, details, for business inquiries, country using curl?

I have already registered my youtube api and didn't found any documentation to get that.

EDIT1:
this is on about page. I can get the data already using 
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=<MY_API>&forUsername=<USER_ID>&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails`

but this thing can't, the `business inquiries`
[image]

Comment: why people downvote without tips on what I did wrong? Just asking some help here T_T.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get 'for business inquiries' e-mailaddress via the API at this current moment.

You can get an overview of what you can retrieve via the API [over here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).